# How to keep input type=file field value after failed validation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I've got a simple form in an MVC app I've made. It contains a file field so users can upload an image. It all works great.

Problem is, if the form submit fails validation the content of the file field is lost (other fields remain populated, thx HtmlHelpers!). **How do I keep the file field populated after a failed validation?**

TIA!

Comment: I've wasted a day on this problem today. It's been 12 years and I can't believe there still isn't a usable, native solution for this. I'm using ASP.NET's `HttpPostFileBase` class in my model for uploading images from a view and it all works very nicely. Then I tried to handle this very simple, common scenario where the posted data fails server-side validation and boom. Hours of fiddling with hidden inputs, converting streams to byte arrays and base64 strings and all sorts. Complete waste of time.

Comment: @Philip Stratford, exact same boat here, really frustrated to have wasted almost an entire day on such an simple problem, i've ended up just returning the model with the file to the view without accessing it directly, and setting a fake label on the view as if the file was still selected on the input

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Browsers are designed in such way because of security risks. It's impossible to set value of file input box in HTML source or by Javascript. Otherwise malicious script could steal some private file without user attention.

There is [an interesting information](https://jkorpela.fi/forms/file.html#value) about the subject.

Comment: yup, I understand the security principle. Just wish it was possible for the scenario I described, simply because I've had the user experience impacted by it. ;/

Comment: To fix your UX problem that the user would have to re-select the file: You can store the file in a temporary cache on the server side when the form with a set file is submitted for the first time. Then if the validation fails, you simple show the filename (or thumbnail) to indicate that the field is set. Once the validation is successful, you fetch the file data from your cache.

Comment: @tsauerwen, well that defeats the purpose of MVCs stateless model.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cannot set the value of a HTML file input box. 
I would suggest coupling the file input box with a label or text box.

Then you can populate the it with the value from the file input box to be resubmitted later.

Comment: Interesting... do you know of a site that has implemented it in this way? Looking for examples... thank you.

Comment: Gmail uses something similar with its attachments. Once the file is uploaded it turns text. However this is done asynchronously using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

If the file isn't too big you could base64 it and use this as value for a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

There are flash based file uploaders. Try one of them. Some of them even falls back to regular file input box if flash and java script is not supported. I advise to look for jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the validation beforehand via ajax and do a partial page update. In this case, you will not lose the file.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to agree with "impossible" being marked as correct answer.
In case anybody is still in search of a possibility, here is the work around that worked for me. I'm using MVC5. The idea is to use a session variable. I got the idea from [ASP.Net Form](https://forums.asp.net/t/1895657.aspx?ASP%20NET%20MVC%204%20Browser%20looses%20uploading%20File%20after%20Postback).

My Model/ViewModel (only relevant properties):

```
public partial class emp_leaves
    {
        public string fileNameOrig { get; set; }
        public byte[] fileContent { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller (HttpPost):
//Check

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(emp_leaves emp_leaves)
{
    if (emp_leaves.uploadFile != null && emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength>0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName))
    {
        emp_leaves.fileNameOrig = Path.GetFileName(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName);
        emp_leaves.fileContent = new byte[emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength];
        emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Read(emp_leaves.fileContent, 0, emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength);
        Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] = emp_leaves.uploadFile; //saving the file in session variable here
    }
    else if (Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] != null)
    {//if re-submitting after a failed validation you will reach here.
        emp_leaves.uploadFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"];
        if (emp_leaves.uploadFile != null && emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength>0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName))
        {
            emp_leaves.fileNameOrig = Path.GetFileName(emp_leaves.uploadFile.FileName);
            emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
            emp_leaves.fileContent = new byte[emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength];
            emp_leaves.uploadFile.InputStream.Read(emp_leaves.fileContent, 0, emp_leaves.uploadFile.ContentLength);    
        }
    }
//code to save follows here...
}
```

Finally within my edit view: here, i am conditionally showing the file upload control.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $("#removefile").on("click", function(e) {
    if (!confirm('Delete File?')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    $('#fileNameOrig').val('');
    //toggle visibility for concerned div
    $('#downloadlrfdiv').hide();
    $('#uploadlrfdiv').show();
    return false;
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
@model PPMSWEB.Models.emp_leaves @{ HttpPostedFileBase uploadFileSession = Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"] == null ? null : (HttpPostedFileBase)Session["emp_leaves.uploadFile"]; } @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"
})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row">
  @*irrelevant content removed*@
  <div id="downloadlrfdiv" @((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.fileNameOrig) && (Model.uploadFile==n ull || uploadFileSession !=null)) ? "" : "style=display:none;")>
    <label>Attachment</label>
    <span>
            <strong>
                <a id="downloadlrf" href="@(uploadFileSession != null? "" : Url.Action("DownloadLRF", "emp_leaves", new { empLeaveId = Model.ID }))" class="text-primary ui-button-text-icon-primary" title="Download attached file">
                    @Model.fileNameOrig
                </a>
            </strong>
            @if (isEditable && !Model.readonlyMode)
            {
                @Html.Raw("&nbsp");
                <a id="removefile" class="btn text-danger lead">
                    <strong title="Delete File" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign">  </strong>
                </a>
            }
            </span>
  </div>
  <div id="uploadlrfdiv" @(!(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.fileNameOrig) && Model.uploadFile==n ull) && !Model.readonlyMode ? "" : "style=display:none;")>
    <label>Upload File</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.uploadFile, new { @type = "file", @class = "btn btn-default", @title = "Upload file (max 300 KB)" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.uploadFile)
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the value of a HTML file input box. As a workaround, replace the file upload box with a hidden input field when outputting the form after validation.

On submission, you populate the hidden field with the value from the file input box (to be resubmitted later). Remember to have either the file upload or hidden field name present at any one time (not both):

**Note:** The code below is for *illustration/explanation* purposes only. Replace it with the code appropriate to the language you use.

```
<?php /* You may need to sanitize the value of $_POST['file_upload']; 
* this is just a start */
if(isset($_POST['file_upload']) && !empty($_POST['file_upload'])){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="file_upload" value="<?php print($_POST['file_upload']); ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "Remember to have either the file upload or hidden field name present at any one time (not both)."  Well, what if, after validation, the user changes their mind and wants to select a different file?

Answer (score 0):

I post/upload images on change, with ajax. Then, show the thumbnails in a div by accessing the file field for the paths.  This allows the user to upload addition photos without losing the original selected images.

Then I remove the html file field and add it back hidden before page submit with all the src values of the div containing thumbnails.

```
            $("form:first").submit(function () {

            $("#fileupload").remove(); // Not needed


                for (var i = 1; i <= $("#images img").length; i++) {

                    var imgFileName = $('#thumb'+i).attr('src');

                    console.log("Views/Product/Create.cshtml => Adding Image for Posting /Product/Create: " + imgFileName);
                    $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "files_uploaded").attr("value", imgFileName).appendTo("form:first");

                }
                return true;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the constraints of input file type like mentioned above, i used following workaround.
My initial view (technically partial view) contains everything, namely all modelproperties including the file model property, the mvc ajax form, the submit button. The difference is, the regular model properties, were again grouped in a second subpartial. Remark in order to do this, the input file is placed a last widget after the subpartial containing the regular model properties, but still in the same mvc ajax form.
So the subpartial doesn't contain the ajax mvc form, nor submitbutton, nor input file type.)
On failing servervalidation, i send back that subpartial with modelerrors to the client, and only that subpartial is replaced on the client, while keeping the original input file type untouched.