# struts 2 action error : retrieves values of form properties

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, struts2

**Problem**

I am using `jsp` to submit a form and `struts 2` action class takes care of it. If there is some problem, then i am sending the result to same page with an error message.

Along with the error message, i want to display property values that he had provided while submitting the request.

**Source code**

Form contains few text fields and few `file` type inputs.

My `CreateRequest.jsp` file:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="myFile1" />
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="myFile2" />
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="myFile3" />
<input type="text" name="operationName" id="operation1" />
<input type="text" name="operationName" id="operation2" />
<input type="text" name="operationName" id="operation3" />
```

My Action class :

```
public class CreateRequest extends ActionSupport {

private List<File> attachment;

private List<String> attachmentContentType;

private List<String> attachmentFileName;


private List<String> operationName

// contains getter and setter for each property

public string execute(){
    // some logic
    //returns error if it fails otherwise success
}
}
```

struts.xml (Action Servlet) file:

```
<action name="createRequest"
        class="action.CreateRequest">
        <result name="success">RequestStatus.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="input" >CreateRequest.jsp</result>
        <result name="error" >CreateRequest.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

**HELP**

How do i get all those values displayed in `CreateRequest.jsp` page, when the action class returns error.

Comment: Any reason not to use Struts2 tags to generate HTML elements?

Answer (score 1):

use ognl  `value=" %{operationName[0]}"` for text box

Comment: what about file type inputs?

Comment: please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967916/how-to-keep-input-type-file-field-value-after-failed-validation-in-asp-net-mvc