# Flask-WTF Filefield value disappear after unsuccessful submit

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, filefield

I have form defined like this

```
class DogForm(Form):
    birthdate = DateField(u'Birthdate', validators=[DataRequired(message=u"User correct form D.M.Y")], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    image = FileField(u'Image of a dog', validators=[Optional()])
    submit = SubmitField(u'Save')
```

template like this

```
{{ wtf.form_field(dogForm.birthdate) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(dogForm.image) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
```

Upon subbmitting, if birthdate is given in wrong form,

```
form.validate_on_submit()
```

stops validating procces and gives back birthday error

view

```
form = dogForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    add_dog(form)

return render_template("dog.html", form=form)
```

My problem is that file path from the FileField disappears in reloaded form and i can not event set it like other values

```
form.image.data = "somepath.."
```

Comment: Please provide the view code.

Comment: I have some other forms as well and everything works fine. This behaviour can be seen only at PasswordField, where it makes sense for security and FileField where it doesn't. I was hoping that there is some way to set it manually, other than form.image.data which apparently does something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep input type=file field value after failed validation in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967916/how-to-keep-input-type-file-field-value-after-failed-validation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the enctype of your HTML form to multipart/form-data

```
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ....
</form>
```

for more detail, check the following link:

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WTF/form.html