# Uploaded file disappers after page gets refresh using jsf and html

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

When I select a file to upload and click on `<p:commandButton>` and if there is some validation error on any inputs and page gets refreshed the uploaded file disappear from the screen and I have to again select the file.

I would like that file instance already selected should not disappear.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please add your source code to see if there's any error

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not allowed by browsers due to security reasons check this answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/968157/1460591

Remember Primefaces and JSF must fellow HTML standards

So on validation phase **JSF** can't just simply hack the `input[type='file']` and force the selection to the submitted file value before 
something like this : `inputFile.setValue(*filePathOfSubmittedFileBefore*)` NOT ALLOWED

**USER ONLY CAN SELECT FILE NO ONE ELSE**